# Why I receive 401 error when using interceptor

Tags: angular

I am developing an angular 9 SPA for a JWT enabled API.

Trying to implement the interceptor below but receive 401 error. What could be the wrong.
Note: Without interceptor, is working fine.

```
import {
  HttpEvent,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpRequest
} from "@angular/common/http";

import { AuthService } from "../services/security/auth.service";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class AddHeaderInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let jsonRequest: HttpRequest<any> = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer " + this.authService.auth.bearerToken,
      },
    });

    return next.handle(jsonRequest);
  }
}
```

Comment: is authorization successfully added on headers? Do you see it in console?

Comment: It looks ok! Debug before return to see if `this.authService.auth.bearerToken` has the value you expect please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting

> 401 Error

is that the `Bearer Token` is not added to your request.

On the other side, the `interceptor` code is a very straightforward code and should work.

**The reasons that make it not working could be:**

1. Not provided in providers part of `@NgModule`.
2. Provided in `@NgModule` but **not defined correctly**.
3. Provided in the wrong `module.ts`

So, the solution is including the following code in the right Module (`SharedModule`/`AppModule`/`WhateverModule`) that the `interceptor` belongs.

```
//import { AddHeaderInterceptor } from "....."
    

@NgModule({
          declarations: [
             ...
          ],
          imports: [
             ...
          ],
          providers: [
            ...
            { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AddHeaderInterceptor, multi: true }
          ]
```